# Какой тип данных у поля transform.position?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня такой, казалось бы банальный вопрос: что мы получаем если обращаемся к полю **transform.position**
P.s. Если я совсем не так делаю, то пожалуйста подскажите как: я хочу получить данные о нынешнем положение объекта.

Comment: Vector3 судя по [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html). А что, в unity нет нормальной IDE, которая показывает тип, когда наводишь на свойство, сигнатуру когда на метод?

Comment: Зайдите к себе в профиль, на все ваши ранее заданные 6 вопросов были даны ответы, но ни один из них вы не приняли, почему? Чтобы принять ответ, нужно нажать галочку слева от ответа, в случае если конечно этот ответ был полезен.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Свойство `position` объекта `Transform` объекта `GameObject` - это переменная типа `Vector3`. `Vector3` используется в Unity для описания позиции в трехмерном пространстве и направлений.

Так что Вы верно понимаете, что это и есть положение Вашего объекта.

Из него можно получить координаты отдельно по осям, например:

```
float xPosition = transform.position.x;
float yPosition = transform.position.y;
float zPosition = transform.position.z;
```

Вот [ссылка на документацию Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) по этому свойству.